# How an exit code is determined in a multithreaded program when one of the threads fails?

Tags: multithreading, c++11

```
struct func
{
    int& i;
    func(int& i_):i(i_){}
    void operator()()
    {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < 1000000; ++j)
        {
            ++i;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    int some_local_state = 0;
    func my_func(some_local_state);
    std::thread my_thread(my_func);
    my_thread.detach();
    return 0;
}
```

Output is

> (process 1528) exited with code -1073741819

What determines the exit code? What does `detach`ing mean for a Windows process?

Comment: C++ doesn't know anything about processes so whatever process exit code you get, it's something OS specific. Your program has undefined behavior so I'd worry about fixing that. Hint: `detach()`ing is almost never a good idea.

Comment: I know about the "bug". I am learning multithreading. What does `detach`ing mean for a Windows process?

Comment: Both threads in your program run within the same process. Detaching the thread doesn't mean anything for the Windows process. It does however mean that you need to find some other way than `join()`ing the thread to make sure it has finished before your program ends or else you have undefined behavior - as in your code in the question.

Comment: @TedLyngmo joining is almost never a good idea.  Top threading design: thread pool, next best: app-lifetime threads, worst by far: create/terminate/join.

Comment: @MartinJames Even with a thread pool you need to make sure the threads are all finished before the program ends unless you want the program to have undefined behavior. If you have other means to do so other than joining that's fine but your claim that joining is almost never a good idea is ridiculous. There needs to be some synchronization to make sure they are all dead. Joining is built-in and for that reason the most natrual way to do this.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, could you give a link to a document stating the undefined behavior?

Comment: @alexander.sivak I think [intro.races/21](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#21) is a good start. "_The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two potentially concurrent conflicting actions, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other, [...]. Any such data race results in undefined behavior._"

Comment: 'you need to make sure the threads are all finished before the program ends unless you want the program to have undefined behavior'.   You may describe the forced termination of threads at process temination as UB but, in many apps, the UB does not matter. In fact, since a hardware or power fail may happen at any time, apps should be designed so that a deliberate termination is "don't care" or recoverable on startup.

Comment: @TedLyngmo ' The execution of a program contains a data race....' who cares if the process is terminating?  The OS stops execution of all running threads as the first step in process termination, so 'The execution of a program' does not apply.

Comment: In many apps, join() is either impractical or just prevents shutdown.  Join is not practical when 50 server threads are in unknown states and using an unknown set of pooled buffers.  Join is notorious for deadlocking GUI apps when devs call join() in 'OnClose' event-handlers when the thread is stuck, waiting for another event-handler to complete.

Comment: The pthreads developers should have dumped join() and added a producer-consumer queue instead.  That fail has resulted in generations of crappy multithreaded apps and devs who are actually afraid of threads:(  If I had been in the position to do so, I would have fired the pthread team for gross incompetence:(

Comment: @MartinJames Having been part of the Pthreads working group (not a team), I can assure you that the behavior of join is one of the least severe inadequacies of pthreads, and that there was not a team in the notion of design team, but rather a group of industry experts trying to prevent Sun and IBM from running roughshod over the checks and balances of the working group.

Comment: @MartinJames secondly, although I often curse how join works; having a generic funnel (similar to wait(2)) has other downsides.   In pthreads, a child can wait (join) for its parents death because their is not a strict inheritance graph; while a queue might be able to provide the equivalent, what if two threads both attempt to join a third thread?   Would one eventually succeed and the other wait forever?  While I don't like pthreads, I have noted that the C & C++ thread APIs make pthreads look brilliant by comparison.

Comment: Shutting down 50 threads in unknown states by brute force - `join`ing in GUI event handlers. Sounds like terrible design.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, although I failed finding a data race (imagine func::i is not a reference), I wanted you to show a document showing that the forced termination of threads at process termination is undefined behavior.

Comment: @alexander.sivak The data race is that the memory is being freed while being used by the thread. This can cause the error you see in your code - or anything really. Undefined behavior is very unpredictable.

Comment: @TedLyngmo no OS I have ever used permits that to happen.  When terminating a process, the state of all not-running threads is set to 'never run again' and all threads running on cores are stopped by hardware-interrupts of the cores.  Only when all process threads are stopped is any memory etc deallocated.

Comment: @MartinJames `my_func` is freed at the end of `main` while the thread is still running so the OS might not be able to help. I think it depends on the implementation what actually happens. A segmentation fault is one reasonable outcome. Like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/8xbW1b) - but on the other hand something completely different may also happen, like the appearance that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, the error code -1073741819 (0xc0020001) is not produced by your executable but by the operating system which decided to kill your process.

You also asked a question (in the comments) about detaching a thread.
This means that you will not use `join()` on this thread, thus you launch it, but you are not interested in knowing when it finishes its work.

---

**EDIT**

In my first answer I misread the example and thought the abrupt termination was due to an invalid memory access through the
uninitialized `i` reference.
It was wrong since `i` is actually initialised in order to reference `some_local_state`.
However, when `main()` returns `some_local_state` does not exist anymore while being still referenced by the thread.
Nothing is said about what happens to the detached thread at the **exact** moment when `main()` returns.
Does this thread terminate immediately *before* the local variables of `main()` disappear? I really have doubts about this...
This probably explains the abnormal termination of the process.